# Understanding of dipole moment and its vector property

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, dipole-moment

I have a trouble understanding the electric dipole moment.

The electric dipole moment formula is
$${\bf p}= \int {\bf r}' \rho({\bf r}')d\tau '$$
I'm interested in the coordinate, the origin of which is changed into $\bf a$.
$${\bf r}' = {\bar {\bf r}}' + {\bf a}$$
Now calculate dipole moment in the new coordinate
\begin{align}
{\bar {\bf p}} &= \int {\bar {\bf r}}' \rho ({\bar {\bf r}}') d\bar\tau' \\
&= \int ({\bf r}'-{\bf a}) \rho ({\bar {\bf r}'}) d\bar\tau'
\end{align}
In Griffiths, it says 
$$\rho ({\bar {\bf r}}') = \rho ({{\bf r}}') $$
so that yields ${\bar {\bf p}}= {\bf p} - Q {\bf a}$.

I don't understand how to verify $\rho ({\bar {\bf r}}') = \rho ({{\bf r}}') $.

Comment: I think, to get $\bar{\bf{p}}$, you need to work with $\bar{\rho}(\bf{r})=\rho(\bf{r}-\bf{a})$. Then you substitute $\bar{\bf{r}}=\bf{r}-\bf{a}$ in order to do the integral. Just using your old $\rho$ and shifting the integration variable will give you $\bf{p}$ again rather than $\bar{\bf{p}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused with the new coordinates system.

You sould correct the above equations like this:

\begin{align}
\bar{\mathbf p} &= \int \bar{\mathbf r} \bar\rho(\bar{\mathbf r})d\bar\tau \\
&=\int ({\mathbf r}-\mathbf a) \rho(\mathbf r)d\tau\\
&=\mathbf p - \mathbf a\int\rho(\mathbf r)d\tau = \mathbf p - Q\mathbf a
 \end{align}

In other words, you should consider a new density function $\bar\rho$.